# Number of gap techniques in American Football

Tags: american-football, defense

While reading [this thread](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/129/difference-between-three-technique-and-five-technique-defensive-linemen) and [this one](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/56/difference-between-one-gap-and-two-gap-techniques-for-defensive-linemen) I had trouble following the football terminology of the different "techniques" for defensive line men.

What does it mean to have a 1 / 2 / 3 / 5 gap technique defensive linemen?

What does that gap mean?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The gap refers to the empty space between offensive linemen on the opposing team at the line of scrimmage. If you have a 1 or 2 gap defensive linemen, it means that he is responsible for keeping the offensive team from advancing through either one or two gaps, or responsible for  advancing himself between the gap and tackling the ball carrier behind the line of scrimmage. See the below example for an illustration.

[image]

In this example the defensive linemen (the four shaded triangles) are all playing a one gap technique as they are only responsible for a single gap in the offensive line of scrimmage.

The offensive team often uses the terms "A-Gap" or "B-Gap" to refer to the gaps on the offensive line. The A-Gap's are the gaps on either side of the center. The B-Gap's are the gaps between the guards and the tackles. The C-Gaps are the gaps between the tackles and the tight-ends. So a running play that was meant to run to the "Strong-side B-Gap" would run to the offensive right (strong-side is determined by the side that the tight-end is lined up on) between the Right Guard (RG) and the Right Tackle (RT).

Comment: Where do I find more info like this? I can never understand the intricacies of football.

Answer (score 6):

Many defenses will number different positions on the offensive lineman to indicate where the defender should line up. It's used as a short-cut. Each team can have their own system. Here are some that are the commonly accepted ones you'll hear on TV:

- 0 - head up on center
- 1 - outside shoulder of center
- 2 - inside should of the guard
- 3 - outside shoulder of the guard
- 4- inside shoulder of the Tackle
- **5 - outside should of the tackle (a wide "5" is common for pass rushers)**
- 7 - inside shoulder of the tight end
- 9 - outside shoulder of the tight end

These apply to both the left and right sides of the defense. Here is one explanation:

http://www.denverpost.com/premium/broncos/ci_14630467

http://sonsofsamhorn.net/topic/55895-3-technique-vs-5-technique/